# Accessing a module/class with same name in a different file in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having 2 different file test1.rb and Report.rb as follows :

test1.rb

```
module List
 module Report
  constants = Report::Category.constants.collect{|c| c.to_s}
 end
end
```

In Report.rb

```
Class Report < ApplicationRecord
 module Category
  CONSTANT1 = 1
  CONSTANT2 = 2
 end
end
```

So I get an error in test1.rb saying undifined method category for list::Report. It is accessing  the module list::Report insted for Report class from Report.rb.
Is there a way to access another class/module with same name as the current file module?

Comment: Module names must be capitalized, so `module list` and `module category` are invalid.

Comment: Ohh sry forgot to capitalize here...i had done it in my program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
constants = ::Report::Category.constants.collect{|c| c.to_s}
```

(note `::` before `Report` that causes constant's lookup to start looking from the outmost context)

Comment: @BadalJoshi then you could accept the answer, probably? :)